# use_env_variable returned undefined in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using the latest version of sequelize and my `server/config/config.json` file is configured as follows:

```
{
    "development": {
        "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
        "dialect": "postgres"
    },
    "test": {
        "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_TEST_URL",
        "dialect": "postgres"
    },
    "production": {
        "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
        "dialect": "postgres"
    }
}
```

My .env file is configured as follows:

```
DATABASE_URL = "MY database URL Here"
```

When I run `sequelize db:migrate` I get the following:

> *Error parsing url: undefined*

Comment: from docker container, I run sequelize db:migrate --env development, but its giving below error,

ERROR: Error parsing url: postgresql//root:password@listings-service-db/db

Answer (score 7):

You aren't defining the variable $DATABASE_URL.

Try this in terminal:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://[user[:password]@][netlocation][:port][/dbname]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution through the source code:
Config file is `.js` instead of standard `.json`.

File `config/config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    use_env_variables: "DATABASE_URL",
    dialect: "postgres"
}
```

And you can run:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

But it did not work as expected, new models were added into database with the same name as a username of laptop ‍♂️ I did not have time to find out from sources.

But I found another solution for sequelize-cli where is argument `--url` is a key:

```
npx sequelize-cli --url postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb db:migrate
```

Comment: I know this is old but you probably want to add require('dotenv').config(); on the very first line.  this also requires dotenv package to be added.  This will work with the js config style and pull in your .env variables or enviroment variables

Answer (score 0):

For windows user

**> SET DATABASE_URL=postgresql://[user[:password]@][netlocation][:port][/dbname]**

Note: change 'export' to 'SET', working at my side

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any question. Thanks.

Comment: You save my day @Zeechan. Thanks

Comment: You save my day @Zeechan. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, when you are going to start a server in the terminal remember to config env like this

> --env development
>
> --env test

**Example** to create migration

```
sequelize db:migrate --env development

sequelize db:migrate --env test

npm run dev --env development
```

the npm scripts above help me to start server in development environment

Comment: didn't solved by sequelize db:migrate --env development.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.sequelizerc` file add `require("dotenv").config()` somewhere at the top.

Your `.env` can look like this `DATABASE_URL=MY database URL Here`.

This should work. If you do not have a `.sequelizerc` file, check the documentation https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#the-sequelizerc-file.